# Post details api call with manage_page permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

We have many client accounts that have recently started returning permissions errors when fetching post details using a page access token with manage_pages permission. Many other client accounts do not have this problem.

The specific error message returned is as follows, (page and post ids blanked)

/_?fields=shares,reactions,sharedposts returned error (#10) This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' or 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.

In our api call we are presenting a recently connected and valid page access token with manage_pages permission; can you provide any advice about how to further diagnose this?

Comment: What API version are you using? Facebook has split the page managing permissions into a couple more specific ones with v7.0 - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/managing

Comment: What exact role(s) do the users in question have on those pages? (Or, which [tasks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/overview-1#tasks) are they allowed to perform, I think they are using new terminology in that regard as well now.)